# On the convergence/divergence of this hypergeometric series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\sum x_n$ a series of positive terms such that
$$
\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{\alpha n + \beta}{\alpha n + \gamma}
$$

I want to study the convergence of this series.

My attemp: because of the above relationship, it is clear that the quotient criterium fails, but we can apply Raabe's criterium and conclude that the series converges for $\gamma > \alpha+\beta$ and diverges for $\gamma < \alpha + \beta$. How about the case $\gamma = \alpha + \beta$?

Comment: WLOG we may assume $\alpha=1.$ For  $\gamma=\beta +1$ the series is divergent. It can be checked that $x_n={c\over n+\beta}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've missed something here, $x_n = \frac{x_0\beta}{(n+1)\alpha + \beta}$, where $\sum\frac{\beta}{n\alpha + \gamma} \ge \sum\frac{\beta}{n\alpha + n}$ already diverges after some $n$.